# Flutter iOS Xcode build was failing

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, cocoapods

My flutter app was working fine for android and for iOS the build was failing.

My pod file code was

```
post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
  end
 end
end
```

[image]

Comment: Have you try run iOS on Xcode and see what error is?
Have you try run `pod clean`, `pod repo update` and `pop install`? Are these commands OK?
Moreover,  What is your xcode ver? I had a problem with new xcode version then I had to add these 

     `config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your podfile code to

```
 post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

If my first solution doesn’t work, you can follow these steps:

1. Backup `ios/Runner` folder.
2. Delete the `ios` folder.
3. Create another project with same name as yours.
4. Paste your Runner backup in the `ios` folder to your new project.
5. Run `pod install` in your `ios` directory.
6. Run `flutter clean` the `flutter run`.

Hope it works.d